# How to force linear movement in space?

Tags: science-based, space

What are some scientifically feasible ways to force linear movement (like in an FPS level) to astronauts in space suits in microgravity?

Comment: putting them on a ship with linear corridors makes sense.  Add in that it is a derelict and you have a reason for them to still be in space suits.  The real question is why do you want them in a flat plane instead of 3d?

Comment: What do you mean? Astronauts in the ISS move quite linearly, from all the videos I've seen.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I'm not looking for a flat plane, what I'm wondering is what ways there are to force someone in a spacesuit to travel in a predetermined path besides just putting them in a contained room. FPS games make use of natural obstacles (rubble, vehicles, etc). These obstacles don't apply in space for obvious reasons.

Comment: a ship, a derelict, or a debris field seem like the logical answers

Comment: Doesn't debris in space simply float away though with little resistance? A ship is fine, but I'm hoping for more creative options.

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you explained more about what you're trying to achieve with this idea, and what medium it's for.

Comment: Newton would say: "every object will remain at rest or in uniform motion in a straight line unless compelled to change its state by the action of an external force"

Comment: @JohnDallman The medium is simply a Indiana Jones esque adventure set in space, but no such thing as artificial gravity exists. The characters move through the use of standard spacesuits. I understand I could just lock them in a ship, but I was hoping for cool ways to use debris/wrecks or maybe some little known scientific principle where there are forced to travel down a path. From my understanding of physics though, there's nothing holding space debris in place, so why wouldn't they just want to push it?

Comment: Debris in a zero-G environment still has inertia, and may be dangerous to touch. But it will also drift around if nothing is holding it in place, so it isn't suitable for the fixed path you want. Nor is there any piece of physics that looks suitable for your purpose.

Comment: If they don't have some kind of propellant, they will only be able to move in straight lines, by pushing off of larger pieces and drifting to other pieces. Newton's laws of motion will tell you much, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting them on a ship or space station where the habitat modules are arranged into a ring so that the whole thing can be spun to create artificial gravity using the [centrifugal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force)? If for some reason they chose to stop the spin one would then experience microgravity inside, and if each individual module was only the size of a room or corridor, then one would have to move through them linearly, at least if one stayed in the interior. [Here](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/artificialgrav.php) is a page with a lot of hypothetical designs for artificial gravity using the centrifugal force, I'm picturing something like the [Hedrick fusion spacecraft](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/realdesigns.php#id--Hedrick_Fusion_Spacecraft) illustrated in [this section](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/artificialgrav.php#id--Spin_Grav_Types--Dependent_Centrifuge):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A fixed path through hazards that can't be bypassed is a very Hollywood sort of idea. To make it work dramatically, use a Hollywood villain, who tells the characters that they need to follow this specific path, as indicated by these low-power lasers, or the ship will blow up.

However, you also need a good reason for the characters to comply, rather than just blow the place up themselves, which would be my reaction. They'll also be very highly motivated to kill the villain comprehensively and with no possibility of escape.

Answer (score 1):

> Astronauts have a saying that, in space, there is no situation so bad that you cannot make it worse. -Chris Hadfield

Rather than forcing them to follow a predefined path, make it so that all other paths are simply too dangerous.  One easy way to do this would be to add some randomness to their movements.  In the real world, nobody's body pushes them in exactly the direction they need to go.  You'd need some coarse corrections along the way.  If you don't have enough propellant to make the corrections, you're a dead astronaut.

There's a few real world examples I'd consider for such development.  The first is that many airplanes do not fly straight lines from takeoff to landing.  Many take a zig-zaggy path which keeps them closer to other airports in case they have an emergency and need to be able to land.  The other example I'd consider, because it might be fun for your players, is that of a Golf course.  They are designed such that a normal player can "play it safe," and try to get par or close to par.  However, many holes have a more dangerous path one can take and shave off a stroke.  You might choose a few places where the linearity of  their progression isn't actually important and give them the illusion of such a dangerous jump.  A few close calls this way, and they'll learn quickly why they shouldn't try to skip whole sections of gameplay!